# How do we create a 100% height column in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make the gray sidebar of [this page](https://aloalerjsite.antoniocarlosribeiro.com/) to occupy the left height of the page, going all the way down the page and touching the blue footer, without hacking it too much with things that might make the page looks higher than it really is.

I have tried using `height: 100%` and `position: table-cell`, amongst many other suggestions I googled, but nothing really worked.

Is it possible using Twitter Bootstrap?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3cb30uz1/1/

Comment: why do you want to use twitter bootstrap?

Comment: because this is a responsive web site and we started doing our own css, but it got too painful to make media queries for all devices...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set `min-height: 100vh` on the sidebar, which would ensure that the height of it is at least 100% of the viewport height. Or, since you have a header, you could use [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to subtract.

In this case, set this on the primary sidebar element:

```
min-height: calc(100vh - 172px);
```